# Как ведёт себя массив?

Tags: массивы, lua

Есть такой вот код:

```
a = {
  [1] = "a",
  [2] = "b",
  [3] = nil,
  [4] = "d",
  ["x"] = "asd",
}
a[3] = nil
a[5] = nil
a[6] = 213
for i = 1, #a do
  print(i, a[i])
end
```

вывод:

```
1   a
2   b
3   nil
4   d
5   nil
6   213
```

Если я комментирую 4 (отдельное внимание, что она повторяется после создания массива) или 6 строку

```
a = {
  [1] = "a",
  [2] = "b",
  [3] = nil, -- 4 строка
  [4] = "d",
  --["x"] = "asd", -- 6 строка
}
a[3] = nil
a[5] = nil
a[6] = 213
for i = 1, #a do
  print(i, a[i])
end
```

То вывод:

```
1   a
2   b
3   nil
4   d
```

Во-первых. В документации пишется что `#a` вычисляется для *последовательности* (т.е. ключи 1,n и без дырок). `nil` - удаляет ключ, т.е. делает дырку, но почему-то длинна массива считается не так.

Во-вторых. По логике строковый ключ `["x"]` вообще не должен влиять на вычисление `#a`, но влияет и каким-то непонятным образом.

Что я делаю не так? Спасибо.

**UPD**
При этом, если по очереди комментировать 8 и 9 строки в этом коде, то вывод ведёт себя предсказуемо:

```
b = {
  [1] = "a",
  [2] = "b",
  [3] = "c",
  [4] = "d",
  [5] = "e"
}
b[4] = nil -- 8 строка
--b[5] = nil -- 9 строка
for i = 1, #b do
  print(i, b[i])
end
```

Comment: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html If the array has "holes" (that is, nil values between other non-nil values), then #t can be any of the indices that directly precedes a nil value (that is, it may consider any such nil value as the end of the array).

Comment: Если в массиве есть дыры, то длина может установиться на любую из них.

Comment: @coder675 я идиот, спасибо, пробегал сегодня глазами эту страницу и такого не увидал, а в русской версии такого и подавно нет.

Comment: @imsysmem [Тут](http://texno.info/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/lua.pdf) кстати этот момент широко раскрыт (на русском).